# How would you go about printing a value based the input value and the input value location in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that will take an input like `hello` and output a value for each letter in the input.

e.g.

- h being 1
- e being 2
- l being 3
- o being 4

so the output for `hello` would be `12334`.

At the moment I have been testing with a and b.
I have some code that gives me the location of each letter in the input.
This is the code I have that is working atm.

```
word = input("word")
wordz = list(word.upper())
let =[]

for i, j in enumerate(wordz):
    if j == 'A':
      let.append(i)
    if j == 'B':
      let.append(i)
```

I just seem to not be able to get it to print in the right order. tried for loops and while loops.
have also tried combing the input list and the location list together and matching them up to get the value of the letter and then print the outcome. But I do believe that won't work and from the small a b testing it doesn't work. as input `aaaa` would be a 0, a 1, a 2, a 3 and in a loop x[0] would just be all the a's together.

I'm pretty new to coding and python so not sure what I'm not seeing.
any ideas or suggestions would be great.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. I'm not sure I understand the problem. The numbers are based on unique occurrences, right? Like `hello` is grouped as `[['h'], ['e'], ['l', 'l'], ['o']]`? If so, what about non-consecutive groups like `wow`? Should the output be `121` or `123`? I'm also not sure why you're having problems with ordering, cause nothing you've mentioned here changes it. Please make a [mre]. For more tips, see [ask]. If this is homework, check out [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). You can [edit].

Comment: What is `x[0]`?

Comment: @James I think you're looking for [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 0):

how about this：

```
def solution(word):
    res, num = {}, 1
    for item in word:
        if item not in res:
            res[item] = num
            num += 1
    return [res[i] for i in word]


print(solution("aaaa"))  # [1, 1, 1, 1]
print(solution("hello"))    # [1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
print(solution("abcdeFG"))  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Could also use that num is the same as len(res)+1.